# Keep folders structure while compiling with grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, pug

I am using grunt to compile some jade files into html ones.

My files look like this:

```
index.jade
|--partials/
           view1.jade
           view2.jade
```

I use `grunt-contrib-jade` to compile them with the following code:

```
    jade: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      data: {
        debug: true
      }
    },
    files:
      [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'src/',
        src: ['*.jade', '*/*.jade'],
        dest: 'dist/views',
        ext: '.html',
      }]
  }
},
```

It works fine, all the file are compiled however it breaks the files structure putting all the files in `dist/views`

Is there a way to keep the structure, i.e. get something like this?

```
dist/views
|--------- index.html
|---------/partials/
                   / all other files
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `flatten` property:

```
files:
  [{
    expand: true,
    flatten: false, // <---- don't flatten the folder structure
    cwd: 'src/',
    src: ['**/*.jade'], // <---- also update your glob to grab all the .jade files at once
    dest: 'dist/views',
    ext: '.html',
  }]
```